# Swift In-App-Purchase: Constant prompt to sign in; incorrectly handling .finishTransaction?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

I include a number of non consumable IAPs but I'm encountering issues when loading my app up as it seems to constantly prompt me to log in to my test account user I setup.

I after looking at similar questions, I believe this was because I had originally failed to add the following line to each .case:

```
 SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
```

As you can see from my below code, this is added to each .case. To re-test I created an additional test account, but I'm now getting the exact same results (on each viewDidLoad I am being prompted to log into 2 test accounts...).

Which makes me think that SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction) is not working as expected?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
}
```

Followed by

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])    {
    print("received response ok");
     if product_id == "xxxxxxxxx" {
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    print("Product Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "Purchased")
                    print("Set key ok")
                    break;
                case .Failed:
                    print("Purchased Failed");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;
                case .Restored:
                    print("Already Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //blah blah
    }

}
```

I am encountering this issue due to the finishTransaction not working as expected, or have the original transaction become "stuck" ?

**EDIT:**
Here's where I call SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

```
func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

}


func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        var validProducts = response.products
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            print(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you triggering the payment?  e.g.: `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)`.  Nothing you have there seems incorrect, comparing it to my code.

Comment: Make sure you log out of iTunes & App Store from settings before running you app.

Comment: Hey @Tony68000 - I've edited the question to show where I call this. I've logged out of iTunes from the settings, I've restarted my device, I've deleted / re-installed the app, I've even deleted the test accounts through itunes connect but still no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has "fixed itself". I presume that now I had added:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
```

each time I was re-logging in, it was finishing the previously "stuck" transactions, and removing them from the backlog?

Either way; it's resolved now.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out that the `.finishTransaction()` above was meant to be in the `func paymentQueue()` method